# Strange autolayout behaviour on collection views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have an issue with autolayout, the console is reporting problems with an image view I have in a cell:

```
RefreshCatalogue[31754:16177989] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103b740 V:[UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa9810371d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103b7e0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa9810371d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103b8d0 UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0.centerY == UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103ba60 UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.top == UIView:0x7fa9810371d0.topMargin + 71>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa980d44a10 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fa9810371d0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103b8d0 UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0.centerY == UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The problem is that if I do:

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

Nothing shows even tho the image view seems to have correct frame, the image property is set.
If I reload the entire collection view with:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

The error is still there but the image shows. The code is open here shall anyone be interested in taking a look:
https://github.com/Ridiculous-Innovations/RefreshCatalogue

Also, all the constraints in the story board seem to be in blue. Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Edit: Needless to say that all the elements, including the image view are on the right place (I did debug frames and set random colours) but the image didn't display till refresh ... sometimes the cells don't display at all

Comment: try deleting the constraints and add them . Try to use priorities.

Comment: Don't add every constraint ,so that it won't satisfy all of them when device layout is changed

Comment: The error message says: "If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints..." Well, you _are_ seeing it. That's a big problem right there. You may have forgotten to set this view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints` to NO. (But I have not checked your code; for a mere 50 bounty points I'm not going to wade through your whole code. Throwing your entire code at the wall like spaghetti and hoping for someone to fix it for you is kind of rude...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints, will check out ... unfortunately have to say that the rest of your comment is uncalled for, unconstructive and even a bit cocky too ... I have helped people before and took a code ref as a additional info that anyone can use if needed, and all that without expecting a bounty.

Comment: Checked your project - it cannot be built because of a missing `LUIFramework`.

Comment: in which device is it breaking up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue with UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.top == UIView:0x7fa9810371d0.topMargin + 71 and parent frame with 0 height (so imageview height must be negative, but this is not allowed), like right after calling dequeueReusableCell method.
Possible workaround for this case is change priority from 1000 to 999 on the most bottom constraint in nested view (Vertical Space - catalogueHeaderCell - Image View and Vertical Space - catalogueCell - Info View).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In second cell some constraints are disabled. that means that constraints are removed for Any Height Any Width. so when you run app in iphone than that constraints conflict with your current constraints.

so remove that highlighted disable constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Views:

`UIView:0x7fa9810371d0`, let's name it `container`
`UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0`, let's name it `image1`
`UIImageView:0x7fa981037490`, let's name it `image2`.

Not let's inspect the constraints

Container `height` is `50`, specified by autoresizing. The height is probably not specified by your collection view. Most likely this is the size of the cell when it gets created before it gets resized to the size specified by your collection view layout.

`image2` is `71` points under the topMargin of container, so it is at least `21` points under bottom edge of the container.

`image1` bottom is aligned with the bottom of the container, so it is above the bottom edge of the container.

Now your last constraint centers `image1` and `image2` vertically so there is obviously a collision.

It's a bit hard to know what you are trying to do but I suppose you should position only `image1` relative to the container and the only vertical constraint for `image2` should be the ones that centers them vertically.

Too see the errors in Interface Builder, change your cell height to `50`, you will see everything broken up. There are just some unnecessary constraints which cause conflict on resizing.

There are also some constraints that are not installed for the current size class. It's possible that you are running the app on a simulator that is of a different size class and has them installed. That means there are even some additional collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it helps me in removing those constraint break in console.

```
yourCustomCell.contentView.frame = yourCustomCell.bounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

check your imageView centerY constrain

[image]

delete this constrain...
this problem is occur because of constrain ambiguity. while adding auto layout you have to apply proper auto layout constrain to imageView.

After deleting centreY constrain if there is ambiguity then xcode will again show you same error, again you have to delete ambiguous constrain.

Answer (score -1):

Well the warning message gives a clue to what is wrong.

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103b8d0 UIImageView:0x7fa9810375d0.centerY == UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.centerY>
```

So to analyse you have two view based objects. One is set to centre its self from top to bottom to the other view (0x7fa9810375d0 to 0x7fa981037490 - these are the views id's)

But also view id 0x7fa981037490 has another constraint,

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa98103ba60 UIImageView:0x7fa981037490.top == UIView:0x7fa9810371d0.topMargin + 71>
```

Which looks like the top of 0x7fa981037490 is being aligned to the top of view 0x7fa9810371d0 plus 71 points.

I haven't downloaded your project but I'd bet that's where the problem lies. Best guess is the centre.y constraints cannot be satisfied because the align top moves the ImageView into a place that breaks it. Try to look at what you have set in constraints visually in your head. You have aligned to ImageViews and aligned one of those to the edge of another view. How will that break? (is what you should be asking yourself)

Try removing a constraint one at a time and build and run. If the warning goes, thats the one that needs fixing. Yes the view might look weird and you can use Command + Z to undo the deletion of the constraints one by one.

Give it a go. Let me know